# Disable shortkey

Tags: google-chrome

I use google chrome on mac, and used to use these shortcuts `command+up-arrow` `command+down-arrow` while writing emails. It used to take the cursor to the beginning or end of the text really quick.

But from a few days, these keys have started behaving differently:

```
Command+Up-Arrow: Opens a new tab
Command+Down-Arrow: Closes current tab
```

Can I change this behaviour somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was not Google Chrome. It was one of my installed plugins that was messing up with short keys. I disabled that plugin and now everything is fine.